# loop on xml element in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new in groovy, I would like to build a new xml from an existing one, but I have a problem in my loop, the expected result is not correct

input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
 <id>0035964572</id>
 <issue_date>20220214</issue_date>
 <request_quote_id>101974792</request_quote_id>
 <request_quote_line_item_id>000010</request_quote_line_item_id>
<expiration_date>20220630</expiration_date>
 <sold_to_party_id>77288060</sold_to_party_id>
 <attachments>
 <file_name>file1</file_name>
 <title>title1</title>
 <type>type1</type>
 <mime_type>mime1</mime_type>
 <location>location1</location>
 </attachments>
<attachments>
<file_name>file2</file_name>
<title>title2</title>
<type>type2</type>
<mime_type>mime2</mime_type>
<location>location2</location>
</attachments>
```

my code groovy:

```
 def Message processData(Message message) {
 def writer = new StringWriter()
 def builder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
 Reader reader = message.getBody(Reader);
 def fichierXML = new XmlSlurper().parse(reader);
 builder.Root {
 RequestQuoteHeader {

  'ListOfAttachment' {
    fichierXML.attachments.each {
     'Attachment' {
       'text_id'('FNAM')
        'file_name'(fichierXML.attachments.file_name)
        'title'(fichierXML.attachments.title)
        'mim_type'(fichierXML.attachments.mim_type)
        'location'(fichierXML.attachments.location)
           }
          }
         }
       }
   }
  message.setBody(writer.toString())
  return message;
  }
```

result: in my output xml, i have wrong concatenations: title1title2 mime1mime2
location1location2:

```
<Root>
  <RequestQuoteHeader>
    <ListOfAttachment>
      <Attachment>
       <text_id>FNAM</text_id>
       <file_name>file1file2</file_name>
       <title>title1title2</title>
        <mim_type>mime1mime2</mim_type>
        <location>location1location2</location>
      </Attachment>
      <Attachment>
       <text_id>FNAM</text_id>
       <file_name>file1file2</file_name>
       <title>title1title2</title>
       <mim_type>mime1mime2</mim_type>
       <location>location1location2</location>
       </Attachment>
    </ListOfAttachment>
  </RequestQuoteHeader>
 </Root>
```

Any suggestions please to avoid these concatenations

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think in your loop you want to use the current item rather than the XML-root:

```
    fichierXML.attachments.each {
     Attachment {
        text_id 'FNAM'
        file_name it.file_name
        title it.title
        mim_type it.mime_type
        location it.location
      }
    }
```

here `it` is the implicit list item.